# How to get current hour and minutes in two digit using go?

Tags: go, time

I'm using time package in go for taking the time into string but there is a problem is that when the time is `9:00 AM or 10:00 AM` then the below code will output for 9:00AM is `90` and for 10:00AM is `100` but if there is time `9:11AM or 10:11AM` then the output for 9:11AM is `911` and for 10:11AM is `1011` The problem is if there is 10:00AM then it will give the minutes in two digits number not in single single digit. The code I'm using is

```
hours, minutes, _ := time.Now().Clock()
fmt.Println(hours, minutes)
```

I want that it will produce the result in two digit like `10:00AM` then it will give `1000` and if there is `10:11AM` then it will give me `1011`.

Basically I want to convert them into the string using:-

```
 currUTCTimeInString := strconv.Itoa(hours) + strconv.Itoa(minutes)
```

Can anybody help me for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    hours, minutes, _ := time.Now().Clock()
    currUTCTimeInString := fmt.Sprintf("%d%02d", hours, minutes)
    fmt.Println(currUTCTimeInString)
    hours, minutes = 9, 0
    currUTCTimeInString = fmt.Sprintf("%d%02d", hours, minutes)
    fmt.Println(currUTCTimeInString)
    hours, minutes = 10, 0
    currUTCTimeInString = fmt.Sprintf("%d%02d", hours, minutes)
    fmt.Println(currUTCTimeInString)
}
```

Output:

```
2300
900
1000
```

---

Or, using `strconv`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    hours, minutes := 9, 00
    h := strconv.Itoa(hours)
    m := strconv.Itoa(minutes)
    if minutes < 10 {
        m = "0" + m
    }
    hm := h + m
    fmt.Println(hm)
}
```

Output:

```
900
```

Comment: can we do it in other way?

Comment: like you are using `Sprintf` in your example. Will you produce the same result by removing it?

Comment: I don't want to use `fmt` to produce this result is there any different method?

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format).

```
time.Now().Format("1504")
```

Note that the reference time in the time package is

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

So the sample code above gives you the concatenated hours(15) minutes(04)

Comment: Aren't you trying to get the hours and minutes in two digit string format? You can try this `time.Now().Format("1504")` and it will give you the proper format.
For example, `t, _ := time.Parse("15:04", "09:11")``fmt.Println(t.Format("1504"))`

Comment: see I tried your example too and this will give me the format `0905` I need `905` https://play.golang.org/p/Kz6uJt8eyaH

Comment: Oh I though the title was "hour **and** minutes". Anyway, the answer by @peterSO should suffice.

Comment: but I show my expected output in question but for your precious time thanks

Comment: @misha not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it works: https://play.golang.org/p/2n1Nf2AUzbn